# How do I open a previous version of a DOORs module?

Tags: ibm-doors

## Problem

When running a long DXL script to generate a DOORs module, I accidentally overwrote an old version of a DOORs module by the same name that I meant to keep for comparison. By overwrote, I mean it generates a whole new document, then saves it under the same name.

## Question

Can I open a previous iteration of a DOORs module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "overwrote"? Did you delete and purge the old module? In that case, you will have to revert to a backup of the database.
Or did you just set new values to existing objects? In that case, if you created a baseline, just open it, you might want to use the “smart history viewer“ (http://www.smartdxl.com/content/?p=418). In the case that you overwrote attributes in the current version, it's more difficult. I think there is no script out there that reverts a module to a state some x hours ago.

Perhaps you can write your own script that goes through the history records of the module, like in [DXL DOORS Retrieve Redlines from Specific History Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054087/dxl-doors-retrieve-redlines-from-specific-history-version) or in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21444153 and with this information display and perhaps restore the old content.

It gets more complicated if you moved, deleted, purged, linked objects in your script

Comment: perhaps this might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618168/how-to-keep-track-of-object-and-object-history-information-in-a-loop

Comment: I have edited my question to clarify what I meant by overwrote.

Comment: I think this would correspond to my first assumption (delete and purge). In DOORS, you just cannot first generate sth then store it under a certain name. you first create a module, open it, add objects etc. then save the module. Afterwards, if you try to create a module of the same name in the same folder, you will get an error.  You can then re-open the module ("edit") and work with the existing objects or delete them and create new ones. (assuming that by "document" you mean "module")